# Cannot call Swift method in Objective-C .m file

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, bridging-header

I have big problem with one part of my code.
I have simple function in my ViewController.swift file (on end):

**ViewController.swift**

```
@objc class Constant: NSObject {
 override init() {}

 @objc class func parseApplicationId() -> String { return "lol" }
 @objc func printSome() { print("teeeeest") }
}
```

Now I have one pod (charts graphic) what was written in Objective-C. So I created Bridging file called:

**myprojectname-Swift.h**

```
#import "EColumnChartViewController.h"
```

In header file of Objective-C file:

**HEADER.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "EColumnChart.h"
#import "myprojectname-Swift.h"

@class Constant;

@interface Constant : NSObject

-(void)printSome;

@end
```

and in my FILE.m I have this:

```
#import "myprojectname-Swift.h"

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];


    Constant * sis = [[Constant alloc] init];
    [sis printSome];
}
```

My problem is:

When I build a project, Xcode call me error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_Constant", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in EColumnChartViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

What I trying to make solution:

- New Bridging file
- Switching off some parts of Build Settings
- @implementation Constant -> Thread 1 error

**I just want to call Swift function into Objective-C file (easy call print console). Thanks for every idea.**

Last words: I've checked so many posts on Stackoverflow.

Comment: Do you have this line inside your podfile? `use_frameworks`

Comment: Yes i have. 

use_frameworks!

Comment: @emololftw : In order to access swift files in objective-C file you need to import project-swift.h file in your objective -C .m file using #import "your_project-Swift.h" and not the bridging header

Comment: What must be inside bridging header please? And i have myprojectname-Swift.h as bridging. So its not correct way?

Comment: @emololftw : there are loads of issue with your code buddy. Bridging header will have only import statements to objective-C file's .h and nothing else. Where as project-Swift.h is auto generated and you need not add anything to it your only job is to make sure that the files gets created and also making sure that it has reference of swift file that you would like to access in your objective-C file. Finally you need not declare interface Constant : NSObject in objective-C file again simply delete it

Comment: Problem not solved :( I really dont know what i can do now

Answer (score 0):

#### Duplicate classes

The main issue appears to be that you have created two classes named `Constant`: one in Swift and another in Objective-C. You can only have one class with a given name.

This `@objc class Constant: NSObject` and `@interface Constant : NSObject` both create the same class. Rename one of these.

#### Possibly incorrect bridging

The Swift bridging header is special. You can't just create a header file and expect that to work in Swift.

Ensure that the bridging header is properly set in Xcode.

1. Click the project at the top to open the config screen
2. Search for `SWIFT_OBJC_BRIDGING_HEADER`
3. Make sure the value points to your bridging header. For example: `myprojectname/myprojectname-Bridging-Header.h`
4. In the bridging header file, put the Objective-C import for the class that you want Swift to be able to use: `#import "EColumnChartViewController.h"`

[image]

#### Other Issues

In `HEADER.h`:

1. remove `@class Constant;`. This is doing nothing for you.
2. Move the `#import` for EColumnChart.h and myprojectname-Swift.h into the .m file *only*.
3. The `FILE.m` should have an `#import HEADER.h`. Every .m must import it's .h!

On the line `@objc class Constant: NSObject`, remove the `@objc`... it's obviously Objective-C because it extends `NSObject`.

As some commenters have stated, you have provided code with an astonishing number of problems. You should really take the time to learn Objective-C and/or Swift first. Start by watching some of the free WWDC videos or Googling for intro to iOS.

Answer (score -2):

Make step by step above

- You use `@objcMembers` above declare class in swift file.
- Import `<"Your_Project">-Swift.h` in `.m` file.

  ```
  objcMembers 
  class ObjectA: NSObject {
     .....
  }
  ```